# How create generic interface for JSON data in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

How can I write an interface or type in Typescript that represents a generic parsed JSON object? I have the following code:

```
export interface JsonLikeObject {
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean | JsonLikeObject | JsonLikeObject[];
}

const myStuff: JsonLikeObject = JSON.parse(`{ "x": { "y": 5 }}`);

myStuff.x.y;      
//        └-> Property 'y' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | JsonLikeObject | JsonLikeObject[]'.
//            Property 'y' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

This fails because the type of `myStuff.x` is a union of all listed types from the interface and indeed the `y` property doesn't exist on the string type.

What I am trying to achieve is to make Typescript narrow the types for a list of valid types on each property access, but I have no idea how can I achieve it. Through an example:

```
const myVariable: JsonLikeObject = { list: [{ subObj: { key: 'my-value' }}] } 

myVariable.list[0].subObj.key
// |         |  └-> value of list[0] inffered to be JsonLikeObject because "subObj" doesn't exist on any other listed type 
// |         |      
// |         └-> value in list inferred to be JsonLikeObject[] or string (because index access)
// |
// └-> value in myVariable inferred to be JsonLikeObject because "list" doesn't exist on any other listed type
```

So instead of comparing to union types, I want Typescript to restrict possible types to only those that can be used in the given position. Invalid types still should not be allowed (eg: adding a `Symbol` anywhere should raise an error as it is not allowed.

How can I achieve this? I assume I should use conditional types and `infer` for this but I could not make it work.

Comment: If you know how to use the data (i.e. you know what properties can be there), then create an actual concrete interface or possibly a few possible variations. Otherwise, at each juncture, you need to test the property to narrow the type.

Comment: I know I can create an interface to explicitly type them. This I already do. My use case is actually typing the parameter of conversion functions that received an unknown value from an external source and return a typed subset.

Comment: A `type` or `interface` is not powerful enough to do that. You will need to use a generic function:  https://tsplay.dev/wQ87GW

Comment: @TobiasS. Your example only works because you pass an explicit object into it, as soon as you replace the value with `JSON.parse(<some string>)` the returned value will be of `any` type.

Comment: Than it's not clear to me what behaviour you are expecting. What do you mean with *"because "list" doesn't exist on any other listed type"* ? And how does the behaviour you are expecting differ from just using `any`?

Comment: I expect TS to narrow types when evaluating my property access. So if the allowed types are `string | MyType` and the `string` type is not possible for that property instead of an error I would like to TS to narrow given property to `MyType`.

Comment: I guess that's not going to happen. TypeScript does not do narrowing based on how you **use** the data. Either use type guards, type assertions or `any` to manually narrow the type.